# Why pressing back button in firefox causes postback?

Tags: asp.net, firefox

I have a simple website with two pages which the first page has a button and redirects to the second page.

In the second page when I press the back button the `page_Load` of the first page runs again instead of reading from cache.

But in IE and Chrome when I press back button the `page_load` is not run again and read the page from cache.

I tested it in Firefox 7 and Firefox 15.
what's wrong?

Comment: I guess there is some setting set in firefox that deletes the cache of page when you leave that. Check you browser options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I had an image with `Src=""` and it caused twice running `Page_Load` and running `Page_Load` when I Pressed back button on browser just In firefox.
according to [this link](http://geekswithblogs.net/bcaraway/archive/2007/08/24/114945.aspx) firefox substitute `scr=""` with `page Url` but IE substitute it with `/null`.

Answer (score 0):

If the `page_Load` is the onload event, then it *should* run when going back if the page is read from HTTP cache.  If it's read from an object cache, it should not run.

That said, Chrome didn't have such an object cache last I checked.  So it's odd that you say it doesn't run there...  Can you post a link to your page?